# who is the child and which is the parent in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm quite new in `Vue.js`. I do some simple exercises about communication between `Vue` components. But I still have a problem who is a child and who is a parent. For example I have this code:

**HTML:**

```
 <body>
    <div id="root" class="component">
  <coupon @applied="onCouponApplied"></coupon>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.css"
   />
   <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
   <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
```

**VUE.JS:**

```
 Vue.component("coupon", {
  template: `
 <div>
   <input palceholder="Put your name" @blur="onCouponApplied"/>
 </div>
  `,
 data() {
   return {
     message: ""
   };
},
methods: {
  onCouponApplied() {
    this.$emit("applied");
   }
 }
});

 new Vue({
 el: "#root",
 methods: {
  onCouponApplied() {
    alert("that's work!");
  }
}
});
```

So.. here I have component `coupon` and `new Vue`. I guess that the `new Vue` is a parent. But... I try to understand, how it is work. Can anyone explain to me very simply how it works? I read the `vue.js` documentation, but still have a problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All components refer to the [Vue instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) you mentioned. So your coupon component is a child of your root div. The parent component is the component that embeds another component.

A "UserListView" would have a list component which embeds user components. The view is the parent of the list and the list could be the parent of the user components.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole app consists of components. **Every** Vue app has at least one component that is the parent component (Vue instance).

**Every other component that you make becomes either direct or indirect child of the Vue instance.**

From [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Creating-a-Vue-Instance):

> A Vue application consists of a root Vue instance created with new
> Vue, optionally organized into a tree of nested, reusable components.

Answer (score 0):

The root div is the parent. You are creating a new [Vue instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) ( `new Vue({` ) and associating it with the div element tagged with an id of 'root' ( `el: "#root",` ). The coupon component is contained within this div element, making it a child.